# Do `lsof` listings include unsynced/delayed writes?

Tags: synchronization, lsof

As a follow up to an answer about [*unsynced files*](https://superuser.com/a/986638/279562) i was wondering if `lsof` counts delayed writes as open files?

If an application has closed a file, but the file is not yet *physically* on the device, but still in the kernel buffer, pending a delayed write to the actual device, does `lsof` list such a file as open or is it closed and invisible for `lsof`? And if not is there a way to determine whether a manual sync is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's considered closed, and will not be shown.

If it considered it open, what file descriptor would you expect it to report? Closing a file removes the file descriptor.

I don't think there's any command that will tell if there are buffered writes to a file. But as mentioned in the other question, the `eject` command on removable media will sync it before returning. Shutting down the system will also sync all files.

This is why you should not physically remove a device without first using a command like `eject`.

Comment: You can use the `sync` command to force buffered writes to disk. `lsof` has nothing to do with the physical data, it just shows logical relationships between processes and files.

Comment: I just looked at the other question, and it gives the same answer about using `sync`.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Always use the `eject` command to be safe.